# c# regex match: length 5-24 with at most 1 underscore

Tags: c#, regex

I want to regex match a string that

- Is alphanumeric only.
- Letters may only be uppercase.
- Total length of min 5 and max 24 chars.
- May include min 0 max 1 occurrences of underscore in any position except the first or last.

I think I have to somehow nest the statements so that the total length is 5-24 but there may be up to one underscore. I have read a few regex tutorials , but can't understand a way to do this. Also have NO idea how to specify the acceptable position of the underscore (if present).

```
[A-Z0-9]{5,24}[_]{0,1}
```

Comment: Thanks but this still results in match even if string is over 24 char total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this in C# code, it's better to check the length of the string outside the regex. (It's possible to cram it inside the regex, but I won't show it here).

```
private static bool Validate(string str) {
    if (str.Length < 5 || str.Length > 24) {
        return false;
    }

    return Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[A-Z0-9]+(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)?\z");
}
```

The regex is:

```
^[A-Z0-9]+(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)?\z
```

If a string ends with new line, `$` can match the empty string before new line, so `\z` is used here to assert end of string.

### [Test code](http://ideone.com/SqErdu)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] fail = {"ABCDacbd", "ACDE", "ABCDE\n", "_01234", "ABCDÉ", "ABCD́Ē", "ABCDEF_", "A_B_CDEF", "AB_C", "1234567890123456789012345", "123456_789012345678901234"};
        string[] ok = {"ACBDEF", "01234", "ABC_DE1", "123456789012345678901234", "12345_789012345678901234"};

        foreach (string s in fail) {
            Console.WriteLine(s + " " + Validate(s));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (string s in ok) {
            Console.WriteLine(s + " " + Validate(s));
        }
    }

    private static bool Validate(string str) {
        if (str.Length < 5 || str.Length > 24) {
            return false;
        }

        return Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[A-Z0-9]+(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)?\z");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks nhahtdh. That seems to be right. I cant break it